# Spearman CI on subset of data

Tags: r

I've calculated spearmans rho for a subset of my data:

```
cor.test(formula = ~ mvd_score + total_jealousy_score,
         data = analytic_data_survey,
         subset = sex == "Female",
         method = "spearman")
```

But this does not give me a confidence interval, so I know I need to use SpearmanCI

```
spearmanCI(analytic_data_survey$mvd_score, analytic_data_survey$total_jealousy_score,
           level = 0.95,
           method = "Euclidean")
```

However, this is not on the subset of female participants, and spearmanCI does not recognize when I enter subset = sex == "Female"
Anyone have any suggestions/guidance?

Answer (score 0):

The manual page for `spearmanCI` does not say that it works with the formula method used by `cor.test`. R has many ways of extracting data (`?Extract`) and subsetting data `?subset`. Here is one approach using the `iris` data set that comes with R:

```
data(iris)
str(iris)
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
setosa <- iris[iris$Species=="setosa", ]
with(setosa, spearmanCI(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
# confidence interval 
#     2.5 %    97.5 %
#  0.625475 0.8836843
# sample estimate          
#  0.7553375
```